# Does C# have some kind of it's own clientside database implemention

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

Does C# have it's own kind of database system like Access/ADO alternative.

I would like to make sure it's in the .NET framework no external libraries.

If no which one would you recommend I should use for a compact, small and lightweight database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [MS SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) that ships with Windows 7 and is a free database engine is an ideal, almost "embedded" into .Net data solution for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It does not, C# is just the language.  The .NET framework does not directly either.

SQL Server Express is one option (though probably not lightweight enough): http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

SQL Server CE is better: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx

...as is SQLlite for .NET: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

If you don't need relational features at all and the data is small enough, you could use XML storage directly.

Comment: data is small but it expands rapidly and I cannot keep re-dumping the whole file over and over again, can't really split the file into chunks either have to seek it, time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to take a looks at [Jet Blue/ESENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c485eff-4329-4dc1-aa45-fb66e6554792.aspx) which is a transactional, indexable ISAM database engine thats shipped with every version of windows since win2k.
There are C#/LINQ bindings [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laurionb/).

Answer (score 0):

I think C# and MS-SQL Server makes the ideal pair for most of the solutions. But if you are looking for cheaper solution you can choose MySQL.

Comment: Yeah but i'm trying to avoid having to tell the client to install mysql I want it all to be self-contained

Comment: For that I think you should lookout for the DBs that comes with Windows, And that is `MS-SQL CE`. But I am not sure about the deployment of your product. But you can add the DLL with the installer.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a popular choice for small-footprint lightweight minimally invasive installations and there's a robust data provider for .NET.